# Установка модулей для pypy через mingw32 компилятор

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

Вопрос следующий: на windows 7 x64 установлен pypy3 2.3.1. При попытке установки pypy/numpу следующей командой:

```
  pypy setup.py install numpy
```

скрипт вылетает с ошибкой `unable to find vcvarsall.bat`.

Погуглив ответ, понял, что это из-за отсутствия Visual Studio. Поскольку нет возможности поставить VS, решил воспользоваться альтернативным компилятором mingw32.

Пробую запустить установку вот такой строкой:

```
pypy setup.py install build --compiler=C:\path\to\compiler
```

Но и тут вылетает ошибка:

```
don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'ns' with 'C:\path\to\compiler' compiler
```

Насколько я понимаю, неправильно распознается строка с path\to\compiler.

Comment: [pypy3 не поддерживает numpy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issue/1567/). numpy не работает без изменений на pypy ([pypy поддерживает свой numpy форк](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy)). Компилирование numpy -- занятие не для новичков. Существуют готовые установщики для CPython на Windows, например, [anaconda](http://www.continuum.io/downloads#34) или можно [индивидуально готовые пакеты для Windows ставить](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Существуют [бесплатные версии Vusual Studio с встроенной поддержкой Питона](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation)

Comment: Именно этот форк я и пытался установить.
Я пробовал пользоваться и anaconda, и EPD free distribution - неплохие сборки, но мне нехватает скорости.
Стек задач - анализ данных, поэтому пробую установить pandas/numpy/pytables на pypy.

Comment: pypy**3** не поддерживает numpy совсем (форк или не форк). Для людей, которые знают С и Питон и для уверенного улучшения производительности на число-дробительных задачах, я бы использовал Cython, который хорошо интегрируется с pandas/numpy/pytables на СPython. Существует [куча компиляторов (статических и jit) для Питона](http://compilers.pydata.org/#compilers): cython, theano, numba, copperhead, shedskin, parakeet, LLPython, nuitka, ocl, pypy, pythran разной степени пригодности. Или инструменты, которые позволяют вызывать код, на других языках: ctypes, cffi, scipy.weave, PyOpenCL, PyCuda.